# Black area after rendering using Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Please help me get rid of the black area on top, I just want a blank white background but the black area kept showing up after rendering using Cycles]

Please help me get rid of the black area on top, I just want a blank white background but the black area kept showing up after rendering using Cycles

Comment: Hello have you checked the Outliner for objects that are hidden in preview but enable for render?

Comment: Scale the Plane that you're using as the 'ground' up further so that it covers the whole area of the camera view or extrude the back edge of it upwards and then bevel that edge.